SharePoint list gallery view preview link
I've been having some trouble with SharePoint list's gallery view for a while now.
I create items from a power automate flow that gets an image link from OneDrive. Now, the image loads fine on standard and when opening the item panel. The issue is when I use gallery view, the image files do not load and only display the file name. I tried looking around for solutions such as editing the gallery's item card's JSON.
But everything I tried doesn't work. And I found out just earlier that the gallery preview image uses a different link to the image. I checked the console log of the SharePoint website and it displays a status 404 and cannot load the images, I checked the link of those preview images and it was not correct. The link is almost similar to the correct one but the domain doesn't have the -my suffix. See format below:
What works (sample) and is used by standard list view and others:
https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/imagepath

What gallery view uses (sample):
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/imagepath

I'm not sure where I can set the gallery view to use the same link as the rest? Any ideas? Thanks!
